# Query ManyToMany relations without a named through field

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have this setup in my models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, null=True, blank=True)
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, null=True, blank=True)
```

Given an author, I want to know which topics he wrote about:

```
def author_info(request, pk):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=pk)
    topics = ????
```

If I had specified a through field, I could use that, but now Django makes the through field for me, and since its supposed to be transparent, Id rather not reference the field (unless there is a proper Django construction for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
topics = Topic.objects.filter(article__authors=author).distinct()
```

Note: you have to use distinct here, because the same topic can be selected by different articles.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been able to find that myself, but apparently I missed it. Gonna check it out now.